# Ignoring empty JSON files while reading JSON files in PySpark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark

**I have uploaded a directory to Google Cloud Bucket having different JSON files in different subdirectories. I am reading the JSON files by PySpark and creating a dataframe. **
The code for reading the JSON files.

```py
import sys
assert sys.version_info >= (3, 5)
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions, types

def read_input():
    ebird_schema = types.StructType([
        types.StructField("speciesCode",types.StringType()),
        types.StructField("comName",types.StringType()),
        types.StructField("sciName",types.StringType()),
        types.StructField("locId",types.StringType()),
        types.StructField("locName",types.StringType()),
        types.StructField("obsDt",types.StringType()),
        types.StructField("howMany",types.StringType()),
        types.StructField("lat",types.StringType()),
        types.StructField("lng",types.StringType()),
        types.StructField("obsValid",types.StringType()),
        types.StructField("obsReviewed",types.StringType()),
        types.StructField("locationPrivate",types.StringType()),
        types.StructField("subId",types.StringType()),
    ])
    df = spark.read.format("json").schema(ebird_schema).option("recursiveFileLookup", "true").load("gs://project-storage/ebirddatacopy")
    print(df.show(100))
   
if __name__=='__main__':
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('ebird').getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('WARN')
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    read_input()
```

**I have used resursiveFileLookup so that it goes through all the subdirectories and picks up the JSON files and add them to a datafame. However, many of the JSON files have just an empty list.**

Directory Structure

- Subdirectory 1:

  - file11
  - Sub-sub-directory 11:
    -file 111
    -file 112
  - file12
  - Sub-sub-directory 12:
    -file 121
    -file 122
  - file13
  - Sub-sub-directory 13:
    -file 131
    -file 132
  - file14
  - Sub-sub-directory 14:
    -file 141
    -file 142
  - file15
  - Sub-sub-directory 15:
    -file 151
    -file 152
  - file16
  - Sub-sub-directory 16:
    -file 161
    -file 162
- Subdirectory 2:

  - file21
  - Sub-sub-directory 21:
    -file 211
    -file 212
  - file22
  - Sub-sub-directory 22:
    -file 221
    -file 222
  - file23
  - Sub-sub-directory 23:
    -file 231
    -file 232
  - file24
  - Sub-sub-directory 24:
    -file 241
    -file 242
  - file25
  - Sub-sub-directory 25:
    -file 251
    -file 252
  - file26
  - Sub-sub-directory 26:
    -file 261
    -file 262
    *And this continues for 125 more subdirectories with same pattern.

One JSON FILE CONTENT
[{"speciesCode": "gocspa", "comName": "Golden-crowned Sparrow", "sciName": "Zonotrichia atricapilla", "locId": "L3972294", "locName": "Twin Acres, 4317 Shelbourne St", "obsDt": "1959-01-01", "lat": 48.4846067, "lng": -123.3367547, "obsValid": true, "obsReviewed": false, "locationPrivate": true, "subId": "S42138998"}, {"speciesCode": "harspa", "comName": "Harris's Sparrow", "sciName": "Zonotrichia querula", "locId": "L3972294", "locName": "Twin Acres, 4317 Shelbourne St", "obsDt": "1959-01-01", "howMany": 1, "lat": 48.4846067, "lng": -123.3367547, "obsValid": true, "obsReviewed": true, "locationPrivate": true, "subId": "S42138998"}]

Empty JSON FILE CONTENT
[]

One JSON FILE CONTENT
[{"speciesCode": "eurwig", "comName": "Eurasian Wigeon", "sciName": "Mareca penelope", "locId": "L4014833", "locName": "Harrison Yacht Pond", "obsDt": "1959-11-14", "howMany": 1, "lat": 48.4097618, "lng": -123.3739221, "obsValid": true, "obsReviewed": false, "locationPrivate": false, "subId": "S25903163"}, {"speciesCode": "mallar3", "comName": "Mallard", "sciName": "Anas platyrhynchos", "locId": "L3972294", "locName": "Twin Acres, 4317 Shelbourne St", "obsDt": "1959-11-14", "howMany": 1, "lat": 48.4846067, "lng": -123.3367547, "obsValid": true, "obsReviewed": false, "locationPrivate": true, "subId": "S25903124"}]

I tried without giving an external schema first, but it shows 'Unable to infer schema for JSON. It must be specified manually'.

After giving the schema externally, it shows an empty dataframe with only the header.

**I want these all json files values to be loaded into a single dataframe and the json files which are empty, I want them to be skipped.**

How do I go about this?

Comment: You should set ```multiLine``` option to ```True```.

Comment: I did     df = spark.read.format("json").schema(ebird_schema).option("recursiveFileLookup", "true").option("multiLine","true").load("gs://big-data-1-project-storage/ebirddatacopy")
It still gives the same output - Empty Dataframe with just the header names and no value

Comment: Then, that means all of the JSON files in the directory are empty. Isn't it what you want? Anyway, post a few sample files and describe the directory structure.

Comment: And a tip - you can use keyword arguments like ```load(..., recursiveFileLookup=True, multiLine=True)```, instead of using ```option()```.

Comment: I have edited to show a shorter directory structure and posted the sample files of JSON. Some are empty and some have values in them. I hope it clarifies up things. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: It's not reproducible. You should post debugging details. See [mre]. I did with pyspark 3.3.0 and Python 3.8.13 installed by miniconda on Ubuntu 20.04. I tested with local files created by copy-and-pasting text data in the question.